# modify typedef declaration within if..else

Tags: c++, types, binary

The problem that I am trying to solve:

Read a binary file and write the contents to a text file. The format of the contents within the binary file are specified by the user using an option, e.g. `bin2txt.exe [filename] [/f]`, where `/f` denotes the contents in the binary file are of float type.

My current algorithm:

declare:

```
typedef int datatype;
```

Use `if...else` or `switch...case` to modify datatype to float, unsigned int short etc. within the main code.

The problem:

datatype is successfully modified within the `if...else`, but switches back to default (here, int) outside the `if...else/switch...case`. This means, I could read binary to a vector then write the vector to a text file within the `if...else` statements. But this way, the code becomes too repetitive (every if block will have a vector declaration, initialization, reading into vector and writing to text file.). It would be better to avoid such repetition.

Could someone please guide me to the write direction. ? Thanks.

Comment: C++ doesn't allow runtime modifications of declarations. All declarations are final at compilation time. You have to think more about your design of your program, and how to handle different types.

Comment: … which means, you can use `#if`/`#else`/`#endif`, or `std::conditional_t< flag, float, short >`.

Comment: You need to distinguish compile-time stuffs and run-time stuffs. `typedef` is compile-time, if-else and switch-case are run-time.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: For example: This works:

typedef int datatype;
int main(){
typedef double datatype;
cout << sizeof(datatype) << endl;
return 0;
}

will return 8 because datatype is now double.

Comment: @Potatoswatter http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional says conditional exists since c++11. I am currently not using that. Is there an equivalent in the older version of c++?

Comment: @user2000581 You didn't change the definition, you only shadowed the old name with a new name. Typedefs also obey the lexical scoping rules.

Comment: @NickyC I realise that, since I declare typedef initially, I will not get compile time error and since I modify declaration within if...else, the modificatino persists within the if...else statements. I need to rethink the algorithm like Joachim says. but in which direction ? something like std::conditional seems an idea, but I currently do not see how this can be implemented to achieve what I want.

Comment: @user2000581 You can implement it manually with template metaprogramming, and a C++03 version is included in [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/conditional.html), but there are many advantages to updating your compiler and using a language spec that is not obsolete.

Comment: Write templated code, and instantiate the appropriate template depending on the application switches (.e.g: `/f` -> `float`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself writing identical code except for the types involved, it's often a good candidate for a template.

A simple (untested) variant with no error checking or input verification:

```
template<typename T>
void convert(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out)
{
    T data;
    while (in.get(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(data)))
    {
        out << data << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream input(argv[1], std::ios::binary);
    std::ostream& output = std::cout;
    std::string format = argv[2];
    if (format == "/f")
    {
        convert<float>(input, output);
    }
    else
    {
        convert<int>(input, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Earlier when I saw the word 'template' in a code, I just skipped and searched for a solution without that word. Now I see what a friend it is!

Comment: Oh, just to share, the first line on wikipedia: Templates are any feature of the C++ programming language that allow functions and classes to operate with generic types. This allows a function or class to work on many different data types without being rewritten for each one.